# Meaning of "_" passed as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I just saw this function

`function reducer(_, { type, payload }) {`

passed to useReducer this way

`const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);`

What is the meaning of the 1st parameter "_" in function reducer?

Comment: It's a convention to mean "this variable is unused"

Comment: Just a clarification, `_` isn't being passed as a parameter to the function, it's the *name* of the parameter the function is accepting. Names generally don't matter outside of  conventions/code styles/cosmetic.

Comment: It's just a variable name. If you are uncomfortable with it you can replace it with `x` or `i` or `ignore` and not change the meaning of the code